# How to make WPF game to draw as fast as you can

Tags: wpf, xna

I am new to WPF and I want to make a program that is like a game. The common technique I see is to update your game in a dispatch timer (say every 10ms). But this is not ideal for me.

In XNA's update method, there is a 'elapsed' time parameter. Knowing how much time the last frame actually used is very helpful for me to decide what I do in the next frame. Is there any similar technique in WPF?

For some reason I have to use WPF and cannot use XNA.

Comment: It is not good practice to try and update the UI at a short timed interval like that. It will be very CPU intensive and the screen will only refresh every 16ms at best. Could you use the animations and storyboards in WPF, triggered by events, to move objects around the screen? It would be much better.

Comment: thanks for the reply. it seems that using storyboard and animiation is the right way to do it.